# Flutter: Display grid of images on PDF

Tags: flutter, pdf, pdf-generation

I'm using flutter with the `pdf` plugin to generate a PDF document where I need to display a grid of images. The images are stored in a `List<File>`.

Here's what I've tried. Keep in mind that all these widgets are from the `pdf` package and not from `material`.

```
GridView(
        crossAxisCount: 5,
        childAspectRatio: 1,
        children: door.images.map((image) {
          return Container(
            child: Image(MemoryImage(?????), fit: BoxFit.cover),
          );
        }).toList(),
      ),
```

Note: `door.images` is the `List<File>`

How do I convert the `File image` (from the `List<File>`) to the `Uint8List bytes` needed for the `MemoryImage` widgets?

Answer (score 1):

Convert your File to imagebytes.

```
final List<int> _imageBytes = await image.readAsBytes();
```

And then convert the imagebytes to your Uint8List.

```
final String _uint8List = base64Encode(_imageBytes);
```

Comment: How about using .readAsBytesSync() to avoid complications with Futures? Can this method cause any issues?

Comment: I think it could cause a race condition if the line that uses the bytes is reached before the conversion to bytes is finished.

Answer (score 0):

Please Create `List<MemoryImage>` instead of `List<File>`

```
MemoryImage(
    (await rootBundle.load('assets/images/whatsapp.png')).buffer.asUint8List(),
  )
```